Low Quality Score on Chinese
Some time ago, a question has been asked on JL&U stating that Writing a question in Japanese does not pass quality standards. 
Well, I think we might have the same situation on this site, so I'd like the threshold to be increased for Chinese posts.
I'm not saying "double it", perhaps that would be too much, but considering that "I missed you so much!" can be written as 多想你呀... Not all expressions are shorter in Chinese or the difference is not always this marked, but still an apposite metric should be established.
Also, it'd be good to decide how this metric behaves in case of mixed posts where both English and Chinese are used.

I asked in MSO chat and they said to wait as they likely haven't had time to review the request yet.

This also came up Treat Chinese character's length doubled and Should we use different word limits in comment for Chinese and English?

I've noticed this is a problem since you raised it. I've kept my eye out and for any post that has Chinese characters, they don't count against the filter and are flagged as low quality.
I will try and chase this up and see what can be done.

If the quality checker is oriented to English (as stated in the Japanese reference), how would it score a poor translation, i.e., the garbage that typically comes out of the Bing or Google tranlators?
If Google was set to "detect language" → English, the checker run on that, and then the mangled translation discarded, perhaps that would work well enough?

It's not explicit, but I think the intent here is to use the translation only when testing the length of the comment.
